# How to track the stickers usage and its installation in iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios10, imessage, imessage-extension

Recently we have added a sticker pack extension to our existing iOS application and published in Appstore.

We would like to find out how many people are really using our stickers app (number of sticker pack installation, not the actual iOS app installation) and what's the most used sticker icon.

**App Details:**

iOS app bundle identifier: com. Company name. Product name

iOS stickers app bundle identifier: com. Company name. Product name. Sticker pack name

Is there a way to implement the analytics feature for stickers pack?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mixpanel Third Party for tracking usage and installs.

You can import Mixpanel.framework in your iMessage extension and then you can track the event.

You can install using CocoaPods by giving new application target in the Podfile like below.

```
target "iMessage Extension" do
    pod "Mixpanel/AppExtension"
end
```

For more information check [here](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone).